# Mocking Google Maps in RequireJS for running tests offline

Tags: google-maps-api-3, requirejs, qunit

I am using the async plugin from https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins to load the Google Maps API:

```
define(['async!//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false'], function () {
    // ...
});
```

This has the consequence of requiring an Internet connexion when running unit tests. Is there a way to mock or otherwise allow code that loads this to run offline without raising a "Failed to load resource" error?

Comment: I was going to suggest Sinon FakeServer, but I see that async plugin uses JSONP. Perhaps you'll need to stub out a version of async plugin during unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to use an empty module in place of my `google_maps` module when running QUnit tests.

`google_maps.js`:

```
define(['async!//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false'], function () {
    return window.google;
});
```

`google_maps_stub.js`:

```
define(function () {
    window.google = {};
    return window.google;
});
```

`requirejs_config_qunit.js`:

```
define(['./requirejs_config_development.js'], function () {
    requirejs.config({
        paths: {
            'google_maps': 'js/lib/google_maps_stub'
        }
    });
});
```